# Kohen following a Mes into a tunnel

Tags: halacha, death, kohen-priest, vehicles-transportation, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

We know a Kohen can not be in the same *ohel* as a dead person. From what I learned, a moving vehicle does not block the *tumah* from coming into the car/van/plane etc. So, if one is traveling in a vehicle, he is technically sitting in one spot each time he moves (only for a millisecond, but he is stationary). The same is true for a dead body in a hearse, car or plane.

My question is, if a Kohen is about to enter a tunnel and he sees a hearse with a dead body (AND **YOU KNOW** THE *NIFTER* IS A JEW), can he enter the tunnel?

Comment: d a, I added two of the three tags you asked for, but I didn't see a need for a "tunnel" tag here. When you get 250 reputation points, you'll be able to make new tags. Until then, if you need a new tag, please do what you did, with a note at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Thanks! There was no real need for tunnel. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In theory the same would apply to the lower level of a multi-level bridge (such as the George Washington Bridge, near Yeshiva University).  While at YU, there were two kohanim with whom I regularly commuted. One asked that we avoid the lower level in case there was a hearse and the other did not care.

Answer (score 1):

No he may NOT enter the cave. A cave is considered a roof and if you apply the logic that a tree is considered a roof so a cohen may not enter a cemetery, then kal veChomer he may not enter a cave.

Comment: A source would be nice. Also, an analysis of all the relevant aspects of the question (the fact that the corpse is in a hearse, for example).

Comment: i don't have a source except saying "gemara class"- but as for the hearse. there is actually a machlokes about planes flying over jewish cemeteries. does the bottom of the plane make the roof or does that top, making everyone in the plane tameh leMes. So using that logic, it most likely is best that he does not go into the cave, but I will ask my rabbi.

Comment: he gave a source - its a roof